# Comparing NodeJS drivers and modules for SQL

Tags: sql-server, node.js, npm

We are starting a new nodejs project. Our current database is MS SQL. We need to select a module and drivers to use. I'm trying to find a good way to compare all of these different tools without needing to install them individually and test them on our systems. I'll find the occasional blog post that compares a few of them, but I often find these articles to be terse and will only say something like "tedious is light weight". I'd like to know how light weight it is compared to other drivers. Are there any benchmarks out there?

Aside from drivers a good module is needed. There are several that interest me such as sequelize, mssql and seriate. Some of these can use similar drivers in their configuration. However, the modules themselves need metrics to compare them. Right now the best method seems to be scanning the documentation and the internet getting information about these modules piece by piece. It seems like npm should have some page that compares the different modules that are offered on it. Keep in mind I'd like a source that has quantifiable comparisons between these modules and drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question might be closed as answer is heavily opinion based.

Anyway, what you could do is to search here: https://nodejsmodules.org then check how popular particular module is by checking download count in NPM, this is probably the best (quick) way to minimise the risk to pick wrong module.

Comment: Thanks Andrei! this has added another metric I can use when comparing! I am worried about this question being closed as well, which is why I tried to put emphasis on "quantifiable" comparisons. The community may still vote to close it as not many of these productX vs productY type questions last.